# How to find out current directory and go to a directory in MySQL console?

Tags: command-line

I have the following instruction in I need to perform to run a web app I that have received:

"Go to the directory where the app is unpacked and type 'gradle jettyRun'."

Sounds simple enough, if you know the commands for finding out your current directory and changing it. The problem is, searching for these basic things only nets a huge amounts of irrelevant answers to much more advanced questions where the same terms are used with a slightly different meaning. So what do they exactly mean by what they say and how do I achieve that? It sound's so simple I'm almost embarrased to have to ask it, yet I'm still dumbfounded by the MySQL command line enough to have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the MySQL command line (`>>>`), or MySQL itself. This is simply saying:

1. Open your *terminal* or *shell*. In Windows, this is called `Command Prompt`.
2. Change the directory to where the files are located, you do this with the `cd` (change directory) command.

Next you simply type `gradle jettyRun`.